# What app tests all of GTK's UI elements?

Tags: software-recommendation, gtk, widgets

I've seen it in screenshots before. What application provides a window that contains all of GTK's UI elements? I need an answer applicable to GTK+2 and GTK+3.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For GTK+3 you have the official `gtk3-widget-factory` in package [gtk-3-examples](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/gtk-3-examples/filelist).

Comment: Awesome, this package is still available on Xenial unlike `awf`.

Answer (score 10):

"The widget factory" doesn't support GTK3. For that you can use "A widget factory":

<del>https://github.com/valr/awf</del> => https://github.com/luigifab/awf-extended

You can install it from the developer's PPA or with official repositories (Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora, OpenSUSE):

```
sudo apt-get install awf-gtk2 awf-gtk3 awf-gtk4
```

Comment: I got it but I didn't have to compile it from source. They have a ppa "ppa:valere-monseur/valr". The ppa is for Oneric. I had it originally set as Precise but I didn't want to do another apt-get update on my painfully slow internet, so I ended up just downloading the deb manually from http://ppa.launchpad.net/valere-monseur/valr/ubuntu/pool/main/a/awf/ and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: @MetaDark There are now PPAs available both for Precise and Quantal. I updated the answer to reflect these changes. You might want to add the repository to your software source in order to receive updates from now on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for "The widget factory". It can be installed from the standard repositories, afaik.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for GTK3, I guess I should have specified that.